# After upgrading to angular-cli beta 31 (from beta 24) the ng lint np longer works

Tags: angular, angular-cli

upgraded to beta 31 of the angular beta 24 version of angular-cli following the upgrade instructions. The last step in the instructions said to do `ng upgrade` which I did and it only asked about overwriting the readme.

Since it did not update the angular modules, I updated them in package.json and killed the node_modules folder and re-did the node install.

I got everything working but when I try to do a `ng lint` it says the following:
No lint config(s) found. If this is not intended, run "ng update".

Is there something I need to do to get the `ng lint` to work in beta 31?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What eventually worked for me was removing the `package.json` file in the `/users/username` folder.

There is a a more detailed discussion here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4207

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install it both globally and locally.  Once I did this everything started to work.  I seems like it uses the global version.  I wish it was more like grunt and use the local version.

Answer (score 0):

No sure if this applies to beta 31 but for rc1, there is a need for more config to use lint, new files and a lint section in angular-cli.json.

See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-rc-update#linting